# "No Output" Return Code Shell Script

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, io, rc

I'm trying to create a script that will kill a process and confirm the process is running before issuing the kill -9 command, I'm running into a bug where it always assumes there is output.

```
#!/bin/sh
rc=$?

#Ask to check for a process to kill
clear
echo "Please enter a process number you would like to kill"
echo ""
read proc
ps -ef | awk '{print $2}' | grep *$proc*
if [[ $rc != 0 ]]; then
        echo "Process not running or already killed"
        sleep 2
        exit $rc
else
        clear
        echo "Killing process..."
        sleep 2
#       kill -9 $proc
fi
```

Comment: You're setting `$rc` before you run the command you want to check.

Comment: `kill -9` is overkill. A simple `kill` should suffice for well-written programs.

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep $proc` is wrong. If you want to kill PID `22`, it will match `122`, `220`, etc.

The simplest way to test if a PID exists is to try to send signal 0 to it:

```
if kill -0 "$proc" 2>/dev/null
then
    clear
    echo "Killing process..."
    sleep 2
    kill -9 "$proc"
else
    clear
    echo "Process not running or already killed"
    sleep 2
    exit 1
fi
```

Signal 0 doesn't do anything, it just tests whether you're able to send signals to that process.

Comment: Actually, the simplest way is to check for the PID directory in /proc as this does not involve any signalling or spawning of additional processes. `if [ -d /proc/$proc ]; then`

Comment: @Geoffrey True, although that's more OS-specific. I know this is tagged linux, but a solution that's portable to just about every flavor of Unix seems cleaner to me. You could send this script back 20 years and it will probably work.